# how run bash script with php shell_exec with passing 2 variable parameter

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu

i want running bash script with passing 2 parameter and show with bash script create file.txt

```
$email = "omdik";
$password = "123";

$page = shell_exec("/var/www/html/aktiva-development/test.sh $email, $password");
```

and this file test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "username : $1 dan password : $2" > /tmp/cekhasil.txt
```

why the file not create, like the bash command is not running, but if script bash like ls dir the dir list will be show, and the access permision for file and folder i was change to 777

thank you for help.

Comment: Did you try enclosing the arguments within double quotes? `shell_exec(‘/var/www/html/aktiva-development/test.sh “$email”, “$password”’);`

Comment: @Armali the algoritma, start from login form, and if the username and password is true the bach script will be run, else username and password is false nothing.

Comment: yeah i am already for trying that, but the script bash is the same not running, @abhishekphukan

Comment: hey i find that error if i runninh that @abhishekphukan the message error is PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in /var/www/html/aktiva-development/verifikasi_new.php on line 49,

Comment: in line 49 is bash script $page = shell_exec(‘/var/www/html/aktiva-development/test.sh “$email”, “$password”’); @Armali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei all i am already solve for this case, solve with change access permision folder and file to www-data:www-data for sh file and php file

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data test.sh and 
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data file.php
```

thanks all for answer

Answer (score 1):

> in line 49 is bash script $page = shell_exec(‘/var/www/html/aktiva-development/test.sh “$email”, “$password”’);

You have wrong `‘`, `“`, `”` and `’` quotes there; you have to use `'` and `"`.

Comment: huahh my head hurts, the result is still the same can't and no error message what, idk again what i must doit

Comment: Proposal: add the line `exec 2>&1` before the `echo` and inspect `$page` then after return in PHP.

Comment: i think the error is wording format shell exec passwing with 2 argument, because in file test.sh under line echo username and password i add echo string something it show in my website, do you now format wording with shell_exec from php and then get at the file test.sh the value

Comment: i already try this format but can't, do you have any reference?

$page = shell_exec("/tmp/my_script.php $my_url $my_refer");
$page = shell_exec('/tmp/my_script.php "'.$my_url.'" "'.$my_refer.'"');

Comment: I don't understand what _reference_ you mean.